# Define struct with Byte range in C

Tags: c, memory, struct

Given these byte range (an example I picked online), how to define this struct in C ?

These are byte ranges and not bit width. Also how in memory would this look like?

Bytes        Description

07:00    The definition of this field is Fabrics response type specific.

09:08   SQ Head Pointer (SQHD)

11:10   Reserved

13:12   Command Identifier (CID)

15:14 Status (STS): Specifies status for the associated Fabrics command.

```
  Bits Definition ->Status (STS)
  15:01 Status Field
  00 Reserved
```

Comment: I am looking for something like uint8_t A : 8

Answer (score 0):

You'll use arrays of `char`:

```
struct {
  char response_specific[8];
  char SQHD[2];
  char reserved[2]
  ...
}
```

You'll need to consider padding/packing issue (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4306186/structure-padding-and-packing)). This is important if you're expecting them to actually be stored in memory consequently (if, for example, you're trying to use it to parse a binary message from a file or a socket).

Alternatively you can just use one long `char[]` and use indexes to access the fields.